# Close Current Fragment when replacing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

this code below opens a new fragment when html link is clicked , i want to close current fragment so it dont stay open in background.

```
  protected boolean isURLMatching(String url) {
        url = "http://bakara2.com";
        // some logic to match the URL would be safe to have here
        return true;
    }

    protected void openNextActivity() {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new bakara2();
        replaceFragment(fragment);
    }
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, someFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: do you still want it on the back stack? replace works by removing the one that is there and adding the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this once!

```
 getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Garry popBackStack() would not work since @Jusna Leema adding fragment as:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, someFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

**transaction.addToBackStack(null);**

Simple remove fragment should work.